# GPS Exact coordinates - android?

Tags: gps, latitude-longitude

I am using from gps for get latitude and longitude of user when is walking, but when I see points(latitude and longitude) it get me points with 2 or 3 meter distance difference.How can I have the exact coordinates .

I am writing my app with android studio.

Please see too:

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39616993/android-user-tracking-google-map)

Comment: As far as I know normal hand-held GPS (such as used on phones) have a precision of  a few meters (at best, with some post-processing). You therefore cannot really do anything about it. You'd need to acquire a professional GPS system. http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0104/rec-gps.html

Comment: Can I use from DGPS in android ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873350/dgps-corrections-on-android

Comment: The only centimeter precision GPS with Real Time Kinematics (RTK) that is affordable is http://store.swiftnav.com/s.nl/it.A/id.4734/.f at $425 +$25 antenna (created from a successful kickstarter campaign https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/swiftnav/piksi-the-rtk-gps-receiver?token=398b4977 )